# How to write the signum fuction in haskell (Type problem)

Tags: function, haskell

I want to write the signum function in Haskell but i can't figure out how to properly
write the type singature so that the function works.

```
signum1 :: Num a => a -> Int
signum1 x | x == 0 = 0
          | x > 0  = 1
          | x < 0  = -1
```

For every parameter of the Num class the result should either be 0, 1 or -1 from the type Int.
So signum1 0.9 should give 1 as result (not 1.0).

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an `Ord a` constraint, such that we can *compare* the value with `> 0`, `< 0`, and since `Ord a` is a subclass of `Eq a`, we thus can also work with `== 0`:

```
signum1 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Int
signum1 x | x == 0 = 0
          | x > 0 = 1
          | x < 0 = -1
```

The last guard is not necessary, we can use `otherwise` for that (which is an alias of `True`):

```
signum1 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Int
signum1 x | x == 0 = 0
          | x > 0 = 1
          | otherwise = -1
```

Comment: Thanks but why can the library function of signum can have this type signature? Num a => a -> a

Comment: @SimonDice: because that is a method of the `Num` typeclass itself: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:signum. In other words, the programme who makes a type an `instance` of `Num` needs to implement that, so this is implemeneted for `Int`, `Integer`, etc. and then these can of course work with a *specific* type.

Comment: @SimonDice It’s part of the `Num` typeclass, i.e. every Type that is a `Num` has a corresponding `signum`, e.g. for `Float`, there is a `signum :: Float -> Float`.

Comment: Complex numbers are not `Ord` (there is no way to consistently define the positive subset of the complex numbers) but `signum` is defined for complex numbers: `signum (3:+4) = 0.6 :+ 0.8`.